# How to fix Unsupported language admob

Tags: admob, firebase-admob

I currently removed all admob code in my app and i update the app with no any admob code. I update the app to a new Version on play Store. I Apply for review in admob but still they said my app have problem
please help me with posible solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the link about the supported languages of AdMob: https://support.google.com/admob/answer/9727?hl=en

> Placing Google ad code on pages with content primarily in an unsupported language is not permitted by the Google Publisher Policies.

You say that you have removed the AdMob code, so you think that are compliant to the policies. But if you don't want to use AdMob, is useless to link it to AdMob and to ask a review. So, if you ask a review with an app with only unsupported language and without the AdMob codes, i think that they think you want to cheat them, adding the AdMob code after the review.

So my advices are:

- Add a supported language to your content (maybe English, that is
  practically universal)

or

- Choose another ad network that support your language

Comment: Yes bro I already add replace the ads with another ad network and I will submit it to play store and request for review